# JSP socket without refreshing page

Tags: java, jsp, sockets

So I'm trying to communicate using TCP sockets creating a client on a JSP page, the problem I'm having is that everytime I submit the form in my page it will refresh the page and create a new Client Socket, erasing the information i had previously (nomeUtilizador). I searched for ways to submit form without refreshing, and tried it (AJAX) but it never actually worked out...

Maybe there's other ways to solve this, like making it so that the socket is only created once... Or the variable nomeUtilizador is made available for every refresh...

```
<%              private void ClienteTCP(String host, int port) {

                try {
                        s = new Socket(host, port);
                        System.err.println("Ligacao estabelecida");
                        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        System.err.println("Streams criadas");
                } catch (UnknownHostException uhEx) {
                        System.err.println("UnknownHostException");
                } catch (IOException ioEx) {

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
        }
                ClienteTCP("localhost", 6000);
                String nomeUtilizador = (String) session.getAttribute("nomeUtilizador");
                String xmlUtilizador = "C:/Users/leonel/workspace/ParqueEstacionamento/WebContent/xml_clientes/"
                                + nomeUtilizador.replaceAll("\\s+", "") + ".xml";
                criarDocument(xmlUtilizador);
                ArrayList<String> listaParques = getParques();
        %><form name="botoes" id="botoes" method="post"
                action="parqueOnline.jsp" onsubmit="submitForm()">
                <input TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="buttonName"> <input type="button"
                        name="botao" value="Estacionar" onclick="showDiv();"> <input
                        type="submit" name="botao" value="Pagar" onclick="pagar();">
                <input type="submit" name="botao" value="Sair" onclick="sair();">
                <br />
                <div id="escolherParque" style="display: none;" class="escolherParque">
                        <label>Parques</label> <select name="parque">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <%
                                        for (int i = 0; i < listaParques.size(); i++) {
                                %>
                                <option value=<%=listaParques.get(i)%>><%=listaParques.get(i)%></option>
                                <%
                                        }
                                %>
                        </select> <input type="submit" name="estacionar"
                                value="Escolha o Parque onde quer estacionar.."
                                onclick="escolherParque();">
                </div>
        </form>

        <%
                String botao = request.getParameter("buttonName");
                if (botao != null) {
                        //do more stuff %>
```

Comment: What you trying to archive? As I know, code in JSP run at server side. So,  when you create a socket using code that you posted, the socket actually created at your application server and not at client side. To create a socket at client side using java, you should use applet. If you need real time communication between your browser and server, you may consider using [web socket](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) or [web worker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the advice man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code that you submitted if the variable is a session variable it will be still available for the next refresh. The only problem is that if the Server you're sending TCP messages knew that variable by communication it will no longer know it because you made a new client. (considering you're using a concurrent server)

A solution is sending that variable again, and programming the server to receive it.